# Running multiple GlassFish with Docker Compose

Tags: docker, glassfish, docker-compose

I have a non-swarm Docker Compose set up as listed below. The problem is that I can access the GlassFish server when there is only one of them (only one service in the compose file), but when there are two services in the compose file, I cannot access any of them (on the exposed ports). The web browser simply says Cannot connect, as if the servers were not running.

Docker-compose starts without error. Do I need to change something to be able to access both GlassFishes?

```
version: "3"
services:

  glassfish:
    image: glassfish
    container_name: glassfish
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "4848:4848"
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - glassfish1

  glassfish1:
    image: glassfish
    container_name: glassfish1
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
      - "4849:4848"
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Comment: Your entry point is a shell, not a web server. Remove those lines

Comment: Removing those lines has made the servers accessible. But now I can no longer attach to their shell to manage them. I must be missing something...

Comment: Why do you need to get into their shells at all? But yes, your missing `docker-compose exec -it glassfish sh`

Comment: I get in their shell to run asadmin, and configure them... I just found a way: docker-compose exec glassfish sh. -- Just realized it's the same command as yours!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The glassfish containers already have a default entrypoint for starting the server. By overwriting this, you're not allowing the server to start with the container.

Your options include manually starting the server within the shell, or removing the entrypoints

If you want to get into a shell after the server is up, then you can `docker-compose exec glassfish sh`